# In Ruby on Rails, what does "resource" mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources

I see the word `resource` in many different places like: *resource Routing*, *resourceful controller*, and *resources: photos*. What does `resource` actually mean?

One more question: What does *RESTful route* mean?

Comment: I recommend reading "RESTful Web Services". The author delves deeply into the ideas of REST and Resource Oriented Architectures. http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529260

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a "resource" in Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686945/what-is-a-resource-in-rails)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's a big question!

I'd start here to better understand what 'resource' or 'resources' does as it relates to routing: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default

The short of it is that that it formalizes a set of actions (for a specific controller) invoked by URL/HTTP Verb pairs that are responsible for modifying the state of a given resource. Think of resources as nouns: Order, LineItem, Offer and think about what you might want to do with those nouns: typically create them, delete them, modify them, retrieve some set of them, etc. As such, resources are often (but certainly don't have to be) your core model objects and/or some composite representation of those core models.

Again - the Rails Guides summarize what resourceful routes Rails very succinctly in Section 2.1 of the above link: 'In Rails, a resourceful route provides a mapping between HTTP verbs and URLs and controller actions'

If you're unfamiliar with REST, Wikipedia has some decent - but not exhaustive - coverage on the architecture: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer.

Comment: Corollary question: what if I'm running a single page app, where I don't want separate views for every action? Does rails still make sense when it seems to favor returning a separate view for each action of each resource? That aspect of the framework always left me a bit confused. I mean, what about a page that displays both Photos and Videos? now I've got the Show action for two separate resources in one view. You can see how I'm mentally having trouble connecting the Rails architecture to real-world application layout.