# What is a "resource" in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Dumb question but I have some lingering confusion of what, exactly, a "resource" is in Rails. The term is used everywhere but I get a funny feeling it might be being used rather loosely. It's referenced in the model, the controller and, quite literally, in `routes.rb`.

Is it the specific route? For example, `map.resources` maps the 7 RESTful "resources". So an example of *one* resource would be the call to, say, the `index` action of a particular class's controller?!?

Is it a reference to the whole page/object being retrieved? or perhaps, more narrowly, a database table? or the row being retreived?

Is it something else?

Anyway, hopefully someone can set me straight...

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Any object that you want users to be able to access via URI and perform [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) (or some subset thereof) operations on can be thought of as a resource. In the Rails sense, it is *generally* a database table which is represented by a model, and acted on through a controller.

For example, you might have a `User` resource (with a `users` table in your DB). This is represented by a `User` model, is mapped to `users_controller` with `map.resources :users` (which then generates routes like `/users` (a collection of User resources) and `/users/1` (a specific User resource).

You act upon those resources by using the appropriate HTTP method when making calls to those resources. `POST` to the resource collection (`/users`) creates a new record; `GET` retrieves a list of resources (`/users`) or a specific user (`/users/1`). `PUT` updates a specific user (`/users/1/`), and `DELETE` destroys that user. The URLs are the same, but the result (and controller action) may be different based on the HTTP verb. The idea, though is that `/users/1` always means "I'm interacting with the User that has ID #1", regardless of the action.

Comment: If I have a resource that is not using a database model (it's using the API of a seperate service for persistence) does it still make sense to use the rails "resource" shortcut or am I better off just defining the routes manually?

Comment: Sure, you can certainly use `resources` to define routes for resources that aren't in the database! If you don't need all the controller actions that it routes to by default, just use `only:` and `except:` to tell it which ones you actually do want. For example, `resources :things, only: [:index, :show]`...

Comment: I know this is old, but I hope someone can answer, does the use of `resources :users` in `config/routes.rb` only for declaring the 7 REST routes?

Comment: @IrfandyJip I'm no expert, but I do know that adding `resources :users` does declare the 7 REST routes for you, which you can verify for yourself using the `rails routes` command. Can you clarify your question though, and explain if you want other routes for `:user`..

Answer (score 9):

Here's a [good article](http://www.stephenchu.com/2007/11/seeing-rails-resources-clearly.html) discussing how most developers think that "Resource" is synonomous with the database table, the argument, I guess, being that mapping to the resource is mapping the controller to that database table (or, with ActiveResource, to another REST url).

Basically, I think a "resource" is "persisted data." `map.resources` maps the 7 RESTful *actions* to a particular suite of persisted data.

But I haven't thought about it too much in depth. Good question!

Answer (score 3):

I think they probably mean it in the general web sense, i.e., [Resource (Web)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_%28Web%29):

> the referent of any Uniform Resource Identifier

I don't think it has anything to do with database tables.

Answer (score 3):

open your model folder, that is a hint of what resources you have!
example: users, pictures, comments...

Comment: Hm.. I don't think this is a valid answer especially from new RoR users. I came up here because I was confused by the tutorials provided in [Getting Started](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), and I only see `concerns/` and `application_record.rb` on `app/models/` (I am on step 5). And I don't see why that would be helpful.

Comment: Irfandry, in rails, a resource are entities that your application has, for example: "users", "pictures" "comments", "likes"... in MVC (which is what rails is based on) you have separate folders for models, views, and a controllers... this is taken directly from the link you provided: "In the Blog application, you will now create a new resource. A resource is the term used for a collection of similar objects, such as articles, people or animals. You can create, read, update and destroy items for a resource and these operations are referred to as CRUD operations."

Comment: Yes I've read that already, however I'm still confused at the time reading that. Especially the sentence "A resource is the term used for a *collection of similiar* objects", it sounds really weird to my head, maybe because english isn't my first language. But I have found a more simple [answer](https://qr.ae/TWvCoh) already. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

A lot of people here say that resources refer to the database tables you have. It might be true sometimes but not necessarily true always. I could give you a lot of examples where you don't have a corresponding table in your database for a particular resource. Hence asssociating it with tables is rather wrong.

I would define a resource as a route which maps to related requests. So instead of declaring separate routes for the actions you want to do you can simply declare them using a resourceful route.In Rails, a resourceful route provides a mapping between `HTTP requests` and `URLs` to `controller actions`.

So say you define `resources :users` in `config/routes.rb`.
 You can now use a number of helpers to the controllers in your application like `edit_user_path` which returns `users/edit` .

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good link: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html

Which basically says: Resource routing allows you to quickly declare all of the common routes for a given resourceful controller. Instead of declaring separate routes for your index, show, new, edit, create, update and destroy actions, a resourceful route declares them in a single line of code:

resources :photos

Answer (score 1):

In [Roy Fielding's dissertation](https://ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2) in which he introduced REST, he does explicitly define "resource" in *5.2.1.1 Resources and Resource Identifiers* in chapter 5.

In the context of Rails, the [Getting Started](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#resourceful-routing) guide gives the following definition:

> So far, we've covered the "R" (Read) of CRUD. We will eventually cover the "C" (Create), "U" (Update), and "D" (Delete). As you might have guessed, we will do so by adding new routes, controller actions, and views. Whenever we have such a combination of routes, controller actions, and views that work together to perform CRUD operations on an entity, we call that entity a *resource*. For example, in our application, we would say an article is a resource.