# what you mean by resource in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am newbie in Ruby on Rails. When do you know that you want to create a resource in rails application? Does each model need a resource?

Comment: Why the close vote? I think this is a good question.

Comment: You probably want to check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686945/what-is-a-resource-in-rails

Comment: Yes.i am checked that answer.i need a clear idea about the model and resources